# sendMail.exe alternative

Tags: python, batch, application, utilities

Have a bunch of in-house batch scripts and what-not that utilize sendEmail.exe, which is an old perl auto-emailer application which can be found here:

[github for sendEmail.exe](https://github.com/mogaal/sendemail)

The problem is that with our migration to office365, and our security policies, smtp requires startls. SendEmail does not support startls (or have a startls option)... while there are options for both ssl and tls: yes/auto/no, none of them work.

One option would be to create something new with python and the smtplib library to replace sendEmail.exe, but I'd rather not re-create the wheel here.

Are there any other popular free utilities or programs out there, that I could easily swap out to fill this role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got another solution for you, and it's your old trusted SendMail.exe to be used in conjunction with [Stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/). Stunnel does support STARTTLS, and it runs under Linux/Windows/MacOS/*NIX.

What's Stunnel now about, you might ask? Well, this:

> Stunnel is a proxy designed to add TLS encryption functionality to
> existing clients and servers without any changes in the programs'
> code.

So basically it enables your old solution to speak TLS; Stunnel does the encryption part of it and SendMail.exe the rest.

This might be the easiest solution for you; instead of replacing SendMail.exe, you are just adding Stunnel which can be done quite fast.

Comment: Awesome! Going to look into that now.

Comment: stunnel solution ended up working! thanks a ton, that was just what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

I would replace this with a more native approach using PowerShell. As [`Send-MailMessage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7) is now obsolete, that leaves us with [`System.Net.Mail`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail?view=netcore-3.1): [`MailMessage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=netcore-3.1) & [`SmtpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-3.1). Supposedly your scripts can pass the variables (and you can fill the missing) to:

```
$mailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($fromAddress, $toAddress, $subject, $body)
$smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, $smtpPort) 
$smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true
$smtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($smtpUsername, $smtpPassword)
$smtpClient.Send($mailMessage)
```